# I'm attempting to fill an array with the 20 most-recent user inputs. When I print the array the wrong ints are ouput

Tags: java, arrays, int

I am working on a simple game for an assignment, which is complete aside from this part that I *cannot* seem to get right. The game must fill an array with the 20 most recent moves, and print those along with a total of the number of moves once the game is over. For example, a user might make 25 moves, but only moves 6 - 25 would be printed. Also the array length *must* be == 20. I will insert the relevant methods:

```
    public void fillMoveStore(int [] array, int into)
{
    if (moveCount <= array.length)
    {
        array[moveCount - 1] = into;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= (array.length - 1); i++)
        {
            array[i] = array[i - 1];
        }
        array[array.length - 1] = into;
    }   
}

public void displayMoves(int [ ] array)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= (array.length -2); i++)
    {
        System.out.print(array[i] + outputText[34]);
    }
    System.out.print(array[array.length - 1] + outputText[33]);
}
```

aside from this, a moveCount is incremented just before fillMoveStore(moveStore, walkInto) is called. I am new to java... so any help or hints would be greatly appreciated! If more information is required let me know, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
array[i] = array[i - 1];
```

You've got it backwards. You're supposed to move the elements down to make room at the end of the array, but instead you're moving them up. Try reversing it.

```
array[i-1] = array[i];
```

Comment: You are spot on! I thought it must be something fairly simple that I was missing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

just use an `ArrayList`,
every move, just use

```
myArray.add(move);
if(myArray.size() > 20){
    myArray.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: If you're using collections a deque is more appropriate. But I assume arrays are required for the assignment.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ArrayList yet, but I'll look into this. Thanks